# How to prevent C# from wrapping my JSON output in my test controller?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc

New to Visual Studio and C#. I'm working on the UI for a .Net Core/MVC React-Redux app (someone else is working on the model and controllers) and as part of development I wanted to wire up a test controller to output some JSON that I am reading from a text file.

It's working except that C# is wrapping my controller output JSON in another set of brackets which is causing problems consuming the JSON in React.

My test controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace AGDemo.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Versions")]
    public class VersionsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/Versions
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<JsonResult> Get()
        {
            var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"..\AGDemo\Api\JSONVersionData.txt");
            var dataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
            Console.WriteLine(dataObj)
            yield return Json(dataObj);
        }

    }
}
```

The console output:

```
[
  {
    "VersionCode": "0ODD6109 ",
    "VersionQualifier": " ",
    "VersionID": "a74bb26c-c23f-e711-80da-0050568f4ab2",
    "ProductID": "WRAP ",
    "PieceName": "HOME ACCENTS ",
    "PrintClass": "WRAP ",
    "FirstInhomeDate": "2017-12-12 00:00:00.000",
    "AccountID": "103448",
    "AccountExecutive": "AMANDA COOK (A291)",
    "AccountManager": "OLIVIA DOWD (13406)",
    "ArtManager": "OLIVIA DOWD (13406)",
    "AdUID": "",
    "Status": "",
    "Queue": "",
    "DueDateOverride": "",
    "IsLocked": ""
  },
  {
    "VersionCode": "0ODD6110 ",
    "VersionQualifier": " ",
    "VersionID": "6ad828e1-c23f-e711-80da-0050568f4ab2",
    "ProductID": "WRPBAN-IN ",
    "PieceName": "HOME ACCENTS BANNER ",
    "PrintClass": "WRAP ",
    "FirstInhomeDate": "2017-12-12 00:00:00.000",
    "AccountID": "103448 ",
    "AccountExecutive": "AMANDA COOK (A291)",
    "AccountManager": "OLIVIA DOWD (13406)",
    "ArtManager": "OLIVIA DOWD (13406)",
    "AdUID": "",
    "Status": "",
    "Queue": "",
    "DueDateOverride": "",
    "IsLocked": ""
  }
]
```

The controller output:

```
[{"contentType":null,"serializerSettings":null,"statusCode":null,"value":[{"VersionCode":"0ODD6109 ","VersionQualifier":" ","VersionID":"a74bb26c-c23f-e711-80da-0050568f4ab2","ProductID":"WRAP ","PieceName":"HOME ACCENTS ","PrintClass":"WRAP ","FirstInhomeDate":"2017-12-12 00:00:00.000","AccountID":"103448","AccountExecutive":"AMANDA COOK (A291)","AccountManager":"OLIVIA DOWD (13406)","ArtManager":"OLIVIA DOWD (13406)","AdUID":"","Status":"","Queue":"","DueDateOverride":"","IsLocked":""},{"VersionCode":"0ODD6110 ","VersionQualifier":" ","VersionID":"6ad828e1-c23f-e711-80da-0050568f4ab2","ProductID":"WRPBAN-IN ","PieceName":"HOME ACCENTS BANNER ","PrintClass":"WRAP ","FirstInhomeDate":"2017-12-12 00:00:00.000","AccountID":"103448 ","AccountExecutive":"AMANDA COOK (A291)","AccountManager":"OLIVIA DOWD (13406)","ArtManager":"OLIVIA DOWD (13406)","AdUID":"","Status":"","Queue":"","DueDateOverride":"","IsLocked":""}]}]
```

The output I'm looking for (which should be the same as the console output):

```
[{"VersionCode":"0ODD6109 ","VersionQualifier":" ","VersionID":"a74bb26c-c23f-e711-80da-0050568f4ab2","ProductID":"WRAP ","PieceName":"HOME ACCENTS ","PrintClass":"WRAP ","FirstInhomeDate":"2017-12-12 00:00:00.000","AccountID":"103448","AccountExecutive":"AMANDA COOK (A291)","AccountManager":"OLIVIA DOWD (13406)","ArtManager":"OLIVIA DOWD (13406)","AdUID":"","Status":"","Queue":"","DueDateOverride":"","IsLocked":""},{"VersionCode":"0ODD6110 ","VersionQualifier":" ","VersionID":"6ad828e1-c23f-e711-80da-0050568f4ab2","ProductID":"WRPBAN-IN ","PieceName":"HOME ACCENTS BANNER ","PrintClass":"WRAP ","FirstInhomeDate":"2017-12-12 00:00:00.000","AccountID":"103448 ","AccountExecutive":"AMANDA COOK (A291)","AccountManager":"OLIVIA DOWD (13406)","ArtManager":"OLIVIA DOWD (13406)","AdUID":"","Status":"","Queue":"","DueDateOverride":"","IsLocked":""}]
```

I have tried testing different controller action types. The result is either what I have shown OR if the action result was set to "Object" my JSON was wrapped in [] without the "contentType", "serializerSettings", etc. params.

I know I could just open the JSON text file directly in React-Redux in my action function but ultimately the UI will integrate with C# controllers and I would prefer to call a controller to achieve this.

Any ideas on what I need to change?

Comment: Don't serialize it yourself.  Just pass the object into `Json(...)`

Comment: When I try that all of the line returns are included and the quotes are all escaped like: [{\r\n    \"VersionCode\": \"0ODD6109 \",\r\n

Comment: Your debugger vizualizer is doing that.  The output is just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return `JsonResult`, not `IEnumerable<JsonResult>`.

This will tell MVC to process that as an `ActionResult`, instead of an arbitrary object that should be serialized as JSON.

Or change it to return `object` and return the object directly instead of using a result.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I think I tried that but didn't realize I also had to change the return statement to "return Json(dataObj);" "yield" was causing a conflict with the JsonResult type.